# Can I use rsync to capture diffs from multiple systems against a baseline?

Tags: rsync

I've got an event coming up where we will have many students using laptops to do work. All of the systems will be duplicated from a baseline image. What I'm trying to do is to capture only what data has been changed/modified on the systems during the event. The first thought was to put a timestamp file in the baseline image and then use 'find --newer timestampfile' to generate a list of files that have changed since the baseline was created and then just back those up. Then it occurred to me that rsync might be able to help with this using the --backup and --backup-dir options. It's ALMOST perfect, except for one thing. Also, it could work based on checksums rather than just a timestamp.

In testing I set up some test filesystems on local disk to simulate the actions. If I run something like:

rsync -cavhP --fake-super --backup --backup-dir=/backup/host1-backup host1-fs baseline-fs

It works fine and I get the difference from the baseline for the first host directory, but any subsequent host directories don't work correctly. It's almost as if they are using a checkpoint set by the first sync.

Is there a way to tell rsync not to update anything in the baseline directory so I can rsync the changes from multiple target hosts against the base?

Thanks,
-d

Answer (score 1):

Some more time with rsync and I've figured out the solution here, so I figured I'd share. The --compare-dest option is the trick.

First, create the baseline for comparison:

rsync -ave "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" /local/path user@backuphost:/path/to/baseline

Then, on each host you want to capture changes from:

rsync -ave "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" --compare-dest=/path/to/baseline /local/path user@backuphost:/path/to/differential/backup

It's important to note that the path passed to --compare-dest is just the path on the remote host. You have to omit the user@backuphost there.

-d